# How to access instance variable of a module from abother module?

Tags: ruby, module

I have module

```
module SomeModule
  @param = 'Hello'
end

module Reporter
  include SomeModule
  def self.put
    puts @param
  end
end
```

When I call `Reporter::put` I get no output, I suppose that `Reporter` module has no access to instance variable `@param`. Is there any way to access that variable from `Reporter` module?

Comment: `self.put` is a class-level method. How do you expect it to access instance variable?

Comment: You are right, what was I thinking about??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance variables are called *instance* variables, because they belong to *objects* (aka "instances"). There are two objects in your example: `SomeModule` and `Reporter`. Both have their own instance variables. `SomeModule` has an instance variable named `@param` and `Reporter` has an instance variable named `@param`. Those two instance variables are completely unrelated, even though the have the same name. Imagine the chaos, if every object had to come up with its own names for instance variables!

> Is there any way to access that variable from `Reporter` module?

No. You cannot access instance variables from different objects. An object only has access to its *own* instance variables.

[Note: it *is* possible using reflection (e.g. [`Object#instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get), [`BasicObject#instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval), or [`BasicObject#instance_exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec)), of course. Lots of things are possible using reflection.]

What you *can* do, however, is create a method that gives you access to read that instance variable. Such a method is called an *attribute reader*:

```
module SomeModule
  def self.param; @param end
  @param = 'Hello'
end

module Reporter
  def self.put
    puts SomeModule.param
  end
end
```

There is even a method which automatically generates such methods for you, it is called [`Module#attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader):

```
module SomeModule
  class << self; attr_reader :param end
  @param = 'Hello'
end

module Reporter
  def self.put
    puts SomeModule.param
  end
end
```

If you want to also write to the instance variable, you also need to define a corresponding *attribute writer* method:

```
module SomeModule
  class << self
    attr_reader :param

    private

    def param=(param)
      @param = param
    end
  end

  self.param = 'Hello'
end

module Reporter
  def self.put
    puts SomeModule.param
  end
end
```

There is also a corresponding method named [`Module#attr_writer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer) which generates an attribute writer method for you:

```
module SomeModule
  class << self
    attr_reader :param

    private

    attr_writer :param
  end

  self.param = 'Hello'
end

module Reporter
  def self.put
    puts SomeModule.param
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this information, that makes so much sense to me now

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
SomeModule.instance_variable_get(:@param)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use class variable instead of instanse variable

```
module SomeModule
  @@param = 'Hello'
end

module Reporter
 include SomeModule
 def self.put
  puts @@param
 end
end
```

`Reporter.put` prints `123` and returns `nil` in this case